# vuejs 401 unauthorized with axios from django backend with token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios

im trying to fetch data from django rest backend with axios in vuejs frontend but each time i get this error. the tokens match but it is still not authorizing.

```
{"message":"Request failed with status code 401","name":"AxiosError","config":{"transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"env":{"FormData":null},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Authorization":"Token838881311c52b89dd937815066e7eb3a3221604c"},"baseURL":"http://127.0.0.1:8000","method":"get","url":"/api/v1/clients/"},"code":"ERR_BAD_REQUEST","status":401}
```

the axios looks like this

```
            axios
                .get('/api/v1/clients/')   
                .then(response => {

                    for(let i = 0; i< response.data.length; i++){
                        this.clients.push(response.data[i])
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
                })
        }
```

the settings in my django are

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES":(
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

Comment: The authorization header should add a blank space between `Token` and its value: `"Authorization":"Token 838881311c52b89dd937815066e7eb3a3221604c"`

Comment: Nice! I will post the answer in case it's useful to someone else

Answer (score 2):

When using `TokenAuthentication` in Django Rest Framework, the `Authorization` header should have as a value a string containing the keyword `Token` followed by a **blank space** and after that the value of the token. In this case the corresponding header should look like:

```
"Authorization":"Token 838881311c52b89dd937815066e7eb3a3221604c"
```

The `Token` keyword may be overriden if needed. To see some examples you can take a look at
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication